# linq query for select two integer columns

Tags: c#, gmail

I add following code for select two columns in table. But return module is underline. Please help me.

```
public List<module_details> GetModuleDetails(int modId)
{
            var module = (from a in connection.module_details
                       where a.module_id == modId
                       select new 
            {
                id = a.module_id,
                marks = a.module_marks
            }
            ).ToList();

            return module;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to return? A list of module_details with only 2 fields valid and the rest invalid, or a new class that consists of only the two fields?

Comment: I want to return the query with only select the module_id and module marks columns.

Answer (score 1):

Your `module` variable is a List of an anonymous type that has the two properties `id` and `marks`. That's what you declare with `new { .. }`.

This can't be returned as a List of `module_details`, because those are completely different types, as far as the compiler is concerned. You need to select new instances of `module_details`:

```
        var module = (from a in connection.module_details
                   where a.module_id == modId
                   select new module_details
        {
            id = a.module_id,
            marks = a.module_marks
        }
        ).ToList();
```

This code examples assumes that the module_details class has those properties, and they are public settable. It is very possible that naming is wrong, or you need to call a (non-default) constructor on `module_details` to do this - depends on the definition of `module_details`.

On the other hand, if you don't want to return `module_details`, you need to change the method signature accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to return just two columns is probably to create a class to hold the data, and return the data as a collection of that class, something like;

```cs
// Types may be incorrect, not sure what the original types are
public class module_subset { public int id; public int marks; }

// Select the two columns a list of module_subsets
public IList<module_subset> GetModuleDetails(int modId)
{
    var module = (from a in connection.module_details
                  where a.module_id == modId
                  select new module_subset
                  {
                      id = a.module_id,
                      marks = a.module_marks
                  }).ToList();

    return module;
}
```

Comment: Dear Joachim, I add following code for displaying the query details. But it is not working.                          dataGridView1.DataSource = (logic.GetModuleDetails(int.Parse(textBox1.Text)));

Comment: @LakshihaGihan What exactly is not working? Wrong result? Error? ...?

Comment: Data not display to the dataGridView1